Does this sentence in bold sound natural to native English speakers?
“He’s a very smart high school freshman. If he studies hard enough, he can go to Harvard in 2027.”
Does the sentence in bold sound natural to native English speakers?

Yes, this seems fine. I can imagine a native speaker saying it. Your question could be improved by you specifying what you are confused by or what particular part of the sentence you think might sound unnatural and why. In general, requests for proofreading or confirmation of whole sentences is not the purpose of this site.

You have been asking  about can in future contexts.  It seems you are going to ask until someone says "You must say 'will be able'  or 'could', not 'can'."

To qualify for reopening and to get useful answers, please edit to explain more about what concerns you in this sentence.

Many British native speakers will ask 'What's a high school freshman?'.

This is an informal use of can and it expresses that the speaker believes there will be nothing to stop the person from achieving the stated goal if the condition is met. It could be paraphrased as:

He’s a very smart high school freshman. If he studies hard enough, there's no reason why he couldn't go to Harvard.

or "I see no reason why ..." which is a tad less certain.
